# Having trouble with transfering 2 different ProductID to the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

i am currently embarking on a project regarding products catalog. I have check box above the image. So whenever, i checked 2 , i want to transfer 2 different Product Id and display 2 images in the next page. However, i am not able to do that. I can only transfer 1 selected image only . is there any way there once i checked 3 checkboxes, it will show me 3 items on the next page? Great help will be appreciated!!

```
void GetCheckedBox()
{
    foreach (DataListItem li in DataList1.Items)
    {
         selectedProducts = selectedProducts + "," + cb.Value; 
         LblText.Text = selectedProducts;

         Product.Add(selectedProducts);

         string url = "CompareProducts.aspx?prodId=" + selectedProducts.Substring(selectedProducts.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);

         Response.Redirect(url);
         //  DataList1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

My ProductID is in string form : 0001,0002, 0003

Answer (score 0):

You can use session and storing a dictionary in session, that can be accessible on next page. 
you need to write response.redirect out of your for loop.

Comment: are u able to write a sample code for me so that i can understand better?

Comment: user something like this...

void GetCheckedBox()
    {
     Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     foreach (var item in DataList1.Items)
     {
         myDictionary.Add(item);
     }
    string url = "CompareProducts.aspx;
     Response.Redirect(url);
    }

Comment: Hi there! It seems that the code u provide doesnt work. It said that no overload method for' Add' takes 1  argument  @Rohit

Comment: use  myDictionary.Add(item.ToString(),"val");

Comment: also use Session["DateCollections"] = myDictionary;

Comment: and use on next page retrieving from session by       Dictionary<DateTime> myDictionary  = (Dictionary<DateTime>) Session["DateCollections"];

Comment: Hi! Sorry to disturb u again. May i know how to retrieve Image from the checkboxes i have selected by using session? I am using datalist but have no idea to display the checkboxes I have selected

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bryianTan/Asp-Net-get-selected-checkbox-value-in-datalist/

Comment: It only shows the latest checkbox and does not show all the checkbox i selected

Comment: its shows all the checkbox we selected. check demo of this http://download.ysatech.com/ASP-NET-Checkbox-value-in-DataList/